# Can we use (id) in if- else condition?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have written my code in following way in cocos2d.

```
id actionTo = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:4.0f];  
id actionTo0 = [CCSequence actionWithDuration:2.0f];
if (m < enemyNumber)
    id actionTo1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToNextScene)];
else
    id actionTo1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToEndScene)];
id actionSeq = [CCSequence actions:actionTo, actionTo0, actionTo1, nil];
[targetE runAction: [CCSequence actions:actionSeq, nil]];  

error: expected expression before 'id'
```

I am getting the above error. Should not we use (id) in if condition ?
I want to get called two selectors by using the if- else condition.
How can I make it ? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler to write

```
id actionTo1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:
                (m<energyNumber ? @selector(goToNextScene) : @selector(goToEndScene))];
```

Comment: Yes.That was really simpler. THank You Kenny.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot declare new variable in that place. What you should do is declare your `actionTo1` variable before if-condition and set its value there:

```
...
id actionTo1 = nil;
if (m < enemyNumber)
    actionTo1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToNextScene)];
else
    actionTo1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToEndScene)];
...
```

Comment: you can declare the variable there just fine but it won't be visible outside the scope of the if or else block

Comment: Yes, but to be able to declare a variable inside if-else statement you will need to put code into {} block and yes - that will limit variable visibility to that block only. P.S. nice blogs btw